# How to Break Apart an Unbreakable Humidifier to Clean It

Tags: cleaning, humidifier

My humidifier of less than 1 year of use no longer works and Google says to clean mineral deposits.

How do I break it apart to clean it and get it working again?

When I google this, it doesn't show my type of humidifier. It shows videos where people break apart humidifier with ease and clean, https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=clean+visible+mist+ultrasonic+humidifier

Every week I always cleaned per Hunter's instructions, but they don't say how to clean mineral deposits.

I contact Hunter and no one is able to help :-(

Below is Hunter Humidifier

[image]

Inside of Bottom Lid

[image]

Hole on Top Lid I am Unable to Clean <- I think if I clean this my humidifier will work!

[image]

Other side of hole with mineral deposits. Steam comes out of here

[image]

Comment: Most things that heat water say to run vinegar though them to clean.  It will be a quite strong vinegar smell, so be best to do outside or in garage.  Rinse out with clean water couple of times.

Comment: Vinegar is one way but a chemical I use often for mineral deposits is CLR , calcium, lime & rust remover , if the vinegar doesn't work CLR probably wood, I would rinse well afterwards in either case.+

Comment: @crip659 I ran vinegar through he opening with mineral deposit but it just runs through. Mineral deposit remains :-(

Comment: @EdBeal how to run CLR through this opening because it will just fall through :-(

Comment: Mariam CLR dissolves on contact it may take a bottle but a 5$ bottle may save your unit.

Comment: Have to turn on humidifier with vinegar in it instead of water, not just pour vinegar though.

Comment: It's not magic.  How effective that will be is limited by the laws of physics. Mineral deposit removal is slow and takes time, either use a tray so you can immerse the part, or use a recirc pump to keep bringing the dissolve fluid back up to it.  Even immersing it, you'll need to slosh it around periodically to circulate it. **However I am not comfortable with the diagnosis.  The unit may be broken in a completely different way, and cleaning mineral deposits could be futile**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the humidifier in your garage or outside. Put a 50/50 vinegar/water solution into the tank and turn it on. Let it run until the solution is gone. This will help dissolve the deposits. If that doesn't do a sufficient job, try using something stronger like 100% vinegar or CLR.

If running it with both cleaner solutions doesn't do the job, take that top lid off, place it in an aluminum pie pan (or similar), then pour either of the cleaning solutions into it until it's covered. Let it soak for several hours.

Once you've got it sufficiently clean (with either method), run a couple of tanks of plain water through it while it's still outside to get rid of the chemical smells, then return it to regular service.

Comment: It is a bit of a nuclear bomb when you need a shotgun but if you are putting this out in the garage with vinegar - I would suggest a cup of bleach the first run, water the next, and finish off with vinegar/water... We do this once a year with ours.

Comment: Where is the - Take a hammer to it to break it open - part of the answer?  I want to see some breaking of unbreakable things.  "*How to Break Apart an Unbreakable Humidifier to Clean It*"

Comment: Since I don't have garage I'll put in aluminum pie pan. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Freeman's [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/216739/42053) provides a good explanation of how to fix the issue so I'd like to provide an explanation of how to prevent it.

Use distilled water in humidifiers if it's available to you.

From https://www.healthline.com/health/can-you-drink-distilled-water:

> Distilled water is a type of purified water that has had both contaminants and minerals removed.

Distilled water should prevent this issue or at least it would offset the issue for countless years.

Comment: thank you good sir, and an excellent point made, as well! _I now adjourn this meeting of the Mutual Appreciation and Back Patting Society._ :)